# Fixed background image on tableView (iOS, Xcode)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm, developing an iOS app that have a tableView and I want to insert a background image to this tableView.

I have added the following code to `[viewDidLoad]`:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

This code shows the image correctly, but when I scroll the tableView the image scrolls together, I want the image to be still and only the cells do the scrolling.

How can it be done?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using backgroundColor,you could use backgroundView.

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
             [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Background Image Set in Objective C and Swift**

Objective C

```
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"xyz.png"];
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
```

Swift

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "xyz.png"))
```